# Trimming trailing duplicates from a list

Tags: python, list

Consider the following list:

```
data = ['A', 'B', 'CAT', 'C', 'CAT', 'CAT', 'CAT']
```

The `CAT`s at the end of the list must be reduced from three to one. There is a `CAT` inside the list (after `B`) that shouldn't be removed. What is a good way of doing this? The number of trailing `CAT`s is unknown and there may or may not be some `CAT`s inside the list. So the desired output is:

```
data = ['A', 'B', 'CAT', 'C', 'CAT']
```

One way I thought of was:

```
count = 0

for i in reversed(data):
    if i == 'CAT':
        count += 1
    else:
        break

if count > 1:
    del data[-count:]
```

It is quite lengthy for achieving a somewhat smaller task.

Comment: so you want 1 cat or 2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
while len(data) > 1 and data[-1] == data[-2]:
  data.pop()
```

This trims trailing duplicates of any kind. If you specifically want to only trim `'CAT'`, it's easy to adapt the code to do that.